# Set output parameter when commit transaction fails

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to roll back the transaction whenever any one of the query fails. If all the transaction is OK, it has to set the output parameter.

So far I have done this.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertAll]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@WO_Type varchar(25),
@WO_Operation varchar(25),
@WO_Source varchar(25),
@RETVAL BIT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @RETVAL = 0
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    BEGIN TRAN;

      INSERT INTO tblTabl1(WO_Type ,  WO_Operation , WO_Source )
      VALUES (@WO_Type, @WO_Operation, @WO_Source, )

      IF @UPDATESOURCE = 1
      BEGIN
          UPDATE tblT2 
          SET SM_SaddleStatus = @SOURCESTATUS 
          WHERE SM_SaddleID = @WO_SourceID
      END   

      IF @UPDATEDESTINATION = 1
      BEGIN
          UPDATE tblT3 
          SET SM_SaddleStatus = @DESTINATIONSTATUS 
          WHERE SM_SaddleID = @WO_DestinationID
      END

      SET @RETVAL = 1
      COMMIT TRAN;
END
```

Is this the right way to return value? Is there any problem with the method. So far it is working fine for me. Before moving to production I need to cross check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'd suggest, using a TSQL Try Catch block to roll back the transaction and give you a different return value:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertAll]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@WO_Type varchar(25),
@WO_Operation varchar(25),
@WO_Source varchar(25),
--@RETVAL BIT OUT
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @RETVAL = 0
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRAN;
    BEGIN TRY
              INSERT INTO tblTabl1(WO_Type ,  WO_Operation , WO_Source )
              VALUES (@WO_Type, @WO_Operation, @WO_Source, )

              IF @UPDATESOURCE = 1
              BEGIN
                  UPDATE tblT2 
                  SET SM_SaddleStatus = @SOURCESTATUS 
                  WHERE SM_SaddleID = @WO_SourceID
              END   

              IF @UPDATEDESTINATION = 1
              BEGIN
                  UPDATE tblT3 
                  SET SM_SaddleStatus = @DESTINATIONSTATUS 
                  WHERE SM_SaddleID = @WO_DestinationID
              END

            return 0
            COMMIT TRAN;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
            rollback Tran;
            return -1
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: It is giving 'Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT?' error.. I moved 'return 0' statemnt next to COMMIT TRAN statement. Now its ok.

Comment: You need to put commit before return value.